# IntelliJ IDEA "no usages found in all places" for methods that are used

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After IntelliJ IDEA update 2020.1 I cant find usage for some (not all) of the methods that im using. Some are highlighted and I can navigate to the place where I use those, other are not. Suggestions how to fix this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Invalidating the caches did the trick for me when I could not find usages of methods and variables outside of the currently opened class after upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.

Depending on which usages can't be found, you will probably need to check the **Clear file system cache and Local History** option in the **Invalidate Caches** dialogue. After restarting IntelliJ and reopening projects, IntelliJ will rebuild those caches.

See the official documentation for information on invalidating caches: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today, deleting the caches did not work.

Then I deleted the `.idea` folder within the project (it's hidden) and opened the project again and its working.

Bear in mind that this will delete some of your local project configs (run configurations, selected SDK,...)

There is probably no need to delete the whole folder, just a subset...

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't able to solve the problem with the option **Invalidate Caches**. Instead, it was necessary to uninstall IntelliJ with all files and re-install it.

Answer (score -3):

This expression is output when you define the variable and do not use it. This statement will be removed if you use the variable with a method.